# Processing - How to handle SVG coloring when saving?

Tags: java, svg, graphics, 2d, processing

I am working on how to load and save SVG files. So far I've figured out how to load, but a couple issues come up when saving the sketch directly to a SVG file.

```
import processing.svg.*;

PShape fbLogo;
PShape legoMan;
PShape load;
PGraphics pgDrawing;

boolean recording;
int count = 1;

void setup() {
 size(640,360);
 fbLogo = loadShape("fb-art.svg");
 legoMan = loadShape("legoMan.svg");
}

void draw() {
 if (recording) {
  beginRecord(SVG, "test.svg"); 
 }
 shape(fbLogo,110,90,100,100);
 shape(legoMan,200,40);

 if (recording) {
  endRecord();
  recording = false;
 }
}    

void keyPressed() {
   if (key == 's') {
      recording = true;
      println ("Sketch saved to .svg");
  } 
}
```

1) I get an error which reads **textMode(SHAPE) is not supported by this renderer.** I'm guessing it's because of how begin- and endRecord() handle file extensions, but I could be wrong.

2) The coloring in the output file is off. For example, this is how it actually should look like:

[image: actual color scheme]

But this is how it outputs to:

[image: output color scheme]